# how to get the coordinates of an element in iModelJS

Tags: typescript, imodeljs

I am new in iModeljs

I want to implement a function that, when clicking on an element, displays its coordinates to the console.
Please tell me how to do it correctly

Comment: Show some effort. Have you written some code? You can look at their [docs](https://www.imodeljs.org/learning/geolocation/)

Comment: I mean, I need the coordinates of an element on the model, for example, to flip the label over this element.

Answer (score 1):

Everything turned out to be easier than I thought, I found the solution by the link https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/issues/44

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [IModelConnection.Elements.getProps](https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/blob/f67c6a3bcaba9fb40f6a162d541241b7b7df3bda/core/frontend/src/IModelConnection.ts#L1150) to obtain the element's properties by ID, which will include its origin if it's a geometric element.